# HTML5 Audio not working in PhoneGap on Android Platform

Tags: android, html, audio, cordova

**Platform**: Android version 4.x

**Issue**: HTML 5 Audio Tag

**Compiled**: Framework Phonegap

I have been trying to play a simple sound with HTML 5, i cant get it to work.

**Config.xml** Did the changes in Config.xml and AndroidManifest.xml

Here is the code which is written in the JavaScript File.

```
var Player = '<audio id = "player" src = "http://example.com/MusicFile.mp3"></audio>' +
            '<div>' +
              '<button onclick= "document.getElementById(\'player\').play();">Play the Audio</button>' +
              '<button onclick= "document.getElementById(\'player\').pause();">Pause the Audio</button>' +
              '<button onclick= "document.getElementById(\'player\').volume+=0.1;">Increase Volume</button>' +
              '<button onclick= "document.getElementById(\'player\').volume-=0.1;">Decrease Volume</button>' +
            '</div>';
```

Also controls on the players aren't visible. It just appears a big black bar. Is there any way to display these controls also. Tried in the CSS. But failed.

Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually injecting that HTML into the DOM? You'd need to do something like `document.write(Player);`. Your code just shows a Javascript string.